# Changing logo image by changing website language

Tags: php, wordpress, navbar

I'm working on our company website. We want to make our logo image change, by changing website's language. 
this is where our logo code located inside < header > tag:

```
<nav id="nav" class="menu-btn-parent">
<a href="/" class="logo"><h1>
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri()?>/assets/img/common/logo-small.png"> 
</h1></a>
</nav>
```

How can I make /assets/img/common/logo-small.png image to change by changing website language from **mysiteurl/en** to **mysiteurl/de** ?

*We are using wordpress.*

Thank you.

We are using **qTranslate** plugin.

Comment: are you using wpml?

Comment: No, we are using qTranslate.

Comment: `qtranxf_getLanguage()` please use this function to get current language of the site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this in your css

```
.l-header #nav .logo h1{background: none!important;}
.l-header #nav .logo img{opacity:1!important;}
```

Comment: Thank you. It has to work very well, but as I have this style below in my css: `.l-header #nav .logo h1 {
    background: transparent url("../img/common/logo-fa-2x.png") center center no-repeat;
        background-size: auto auto;
    background-size: 100%;
}` it only shows this bg, do u have a hint for me?

Comment: do you mean above code not show logo image not appearing according to language and only the background image which is cumming through css show ?

Comment: I think logo will change by language as well. But cause of that existence css, it only shows (“../img/common/logo-fa-2x.png”). Please check the website http://faradid-honar.com/en

Comment: Actually, I think I need an" if statement " to change .l-header style.

Comment: in the site  logo is managed through css , so you just need to add a class on logo h1 tag according to language and then based on that class you can set different background image(logo) ,

so i am updating the answer please check